# Command not firing on button click on iPhone devices, but is firing on iOS emulator and Android devices

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I test my Xamarin Form app on Android devices and iOS emulators, all the commands on button clicks work perfectly fine.

However, when I test the app on iPhone 12 pro (debugging on iPhone and downloading app from TestFlight), commands are not firing on button clicks.

I have done hours of searching but still can't find out what's wrong with my code. Thanks in advance!

**HomeAnonymousPage.Xml**:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyMobile.Views.HomeAnonymousPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyMobile.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:HomeAnonymousViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
            <Color x:Key="VivaOrange">#F06036</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Accent}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ContentView Padding="0,40,0,40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image Source="my_logo.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="64" />
                </ContentView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10">                
                
                <Button x:Name="btnOpenViva" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="Learn more"
                        Command="{Binding OpenMyWebCommand}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                        TextColor="White" />

                <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="Login"
                        Command="{Binding OpenLoginPageCommand}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource VivaOrange}"
                        TextColor="White" />

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**HomeAnonymousViewModel:**

```
    public class HomeAnonymousViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {    
        public HomeAnonymousViewModel()
        {
            Title = "my Mobile";
            OpenMyWebCommand = new Command(async () => await Browser.OpenAsync("google.com"));
            OpenLoginPageCommand = new Command(async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{ nameof(LoginPage)}?TargetURL={AppSettingsManager.Settings["HomeUriPath"]}"));
        }

        public ICommand OpenMyWebCommand { get; set;}
        public ICommand OpenLoginPageCommand { get; set;}
    }
```

**HomeAnonymousPage.cs:**

```
   [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomeAnonymousPage : ContentPage
    {
        HomeAnonymousViewModel vm;

        public HomeAnonymousPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            vm = (HomeAnonymousViewModel)this.BindingContext;
            
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

    }
```

Comment: First step is to find out whether it is true that the command is not firing, versus the alternative, which is some problem with the commands themselves. Maybe something about iPhone permissions on a real device? As a test, do something simple in a command. Perhaps change the text of a label being displayed. Does that command work? Also, did you say it doesn't work even when debugging? If so, then put `Browser.OpenAsync("google.com")` inside a method. So you can put a breakpoint on that line, see if it is reached.

Comment: Can you tell me if it works fine when you connect your iPhone to debug? Or is this only the case with downloading app from TestFlight.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I found out that the whole page is not responding on iPhone. So here's what I did: I changed the MainPage to my login page, just to see if the issue exists on other pages, and it turns out that the text fields (<Entry> tags) are not tabbable as well (keyboard not showing up). All buttons, checkboxes, and text fields, are not able to be clicked or tabbed. Hence the commands are not firing. Do you have experience with this situation?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT No, both are not working, either connecting my iPhone or downloading from TestFlight gave me same result.

Comment: Something is wrong with that page.  Any relevant error or warning in VS Output Pane? Comment out everything in xaml and code behind. Start adding it back. Try to find what exactly causes the page to "break".

Comment: Do you get errors or warnings in VS when you use your iPhone to debug?